# React js: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I know this is most common question but here
I'm creating the todo react app,i've just started using react but the thing is i'm already passing the `id` and then using  as the key prop in the `Todo` Component,

i tried some of the solutions usally those works but this time i cannot understand even though i'm passing the `id` then using as the `key`
then why this error is occuring

```
import React from "react";
import Todo from "./todo";
const taskList = ({ items }) => {
    let itemsDisplay = [];

    if (items.length > 0) {

        itemsDisplay = items.map((todo, i) => {
            return <Todo id={i} todo={todo} />
        });
    }
    return (
        <>
            {itemsDisplay}
        </>
    )

}


export default taskList;
```

this is my taskList which will receiver the list of task and those task are the array of objects

this is my todo component

```
import React from "react";
import './todo.css'
const Todo = ({ id, todo }) => {
    console.log(id, todo);
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <li
                style={{
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    marginRight: "1rem"
                }}
                key={id}
                className={todo.complete ? "strike" : ""} >
                {todo.task}
            </li>

            <button  >
                Edit
            </button>
            <button >
                Delete buttn
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: move your key attribute to the Todo element. ```return <Todo key={i} todo={todo} />``` and remove it from the <li>

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide a `key` attribute from React while you iterate not an `id` attribute:

```
 itemsDisplay = items.map((todo, i) => {
        return <Todo key={i} todo={todo} />
    });
```

**A quick tip:**
Always provide your key at the time of iteration (while you are iterating), in your case you are iterating with `map()` function, so this helps avoid confusion.

From the child Todo, it doesn't work in this case. React works like that.

Comment: i thought we could only pass the `key` to the jsx tags i didn't knew this thanks man

Comment: My Please mate. We can put to the Components as well while we are iterating or mapping. (General Rule to avoid confusion brother)

Comment: i'll keep this in my mind thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `key={id}` on the `div´, so your todo component should look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import './todo.css'
const Todo = ({ id, todo }) => {
    console.log(id, todo);
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }} key={id}>
            <li
                style={{
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    marginRight: "1rem"
                }}
                className={todo.complete ? "strike" : ""} >
                {todo.task}
            </li>

            <button  >
                Edit
            </button>
            <button >
                Delete buttn
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo;
```

React uses the key prop create a relationship between the component and the DOM element. The library uses this relationship to determine whether or not the component should be re-rendered.

Comment: Nope dude this won't work i tried this already by giving the key to the div but it still show the error like i mentioned btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Your component name should be in PascalCase. I would also suggest giving it name like `Todos` since it's building a list of todos, and consistency is useful for debugging.
2. There's no need to create an empty array in the component. Presumably the data you're passing in the component is an array so all you need to do is check if the array is empty. If it is return something to show there's no data - otherwise use `map` to iterate over the array.
3. **Re the question**: the `key` property should added *during the `map` iteration process*. It is not something that needs to be passed down to the component. It's merely a way for React to better reconcile changes if you choose to reorder the list, for example.
4. On that last point you shouldn't be using the `map` index for the key value. *Hopefully* your todo objects will each have an id. If they don't think about adding one. You can then use it as the key, and also as the mechanism by which todos can then be completed/deleted when you add that code.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Todos({ todos }) {

  if (!todos.length) return <div>Empty</div>;

  return (
    <section>
      {todos.map(todo => {
        return <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />
      })}
    </section>
  );

}

function Todo({ todo }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <li
        style={{
          cursor: "pointer",
          marginRight: "1rem"
        }}
        className={todo.complete ? "strike" : ""}
      >{todo.task}
      </li>
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const todos = [
  { id: 1, task: 'Write task 1', complete: false },
  { id: 2, task: 'Write task 2', complete: false },
  { id: 3, task: 'Write task 3', complete: false }
];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Todos todos={todos} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `Hy mate thanks for the useful suggestions this is my Todolist component`

`   import React from "react";
import Todo from "./todo";
const Tasklist = ({ items }) => {

    return (
        <>
            {items.map((todo, i) => {
                return <Todo key={i} todo={todo} />
            })}
        </>
    )

}


export default Tasklist; 
`


and for the check i'm already doing this in my app component so the check in the that component was no need 

lastly the thing about the id i was planing to assign the id as the variable

Comment: so basically what you're saying is that when we iterator over something then we need to pass key to elemet for eg here we have div and then `li`  in it right so i'll not be passing to the li instead i'll set the key on the div since,sicnce the list i'm making or iterating throught the list

Comment: @Sameer. It depends. In `Todos` we're using a `Todo` component on each iteration so the key goes on that.